# How to use if condition in find() query?

Tags: yii2-advanced-app

I want to put condition like this, I mean if the id does not equal to blank then this wherein condition will add for the same how it's possible?

```
User::find()->
    if($id != "")
       {
           where('id in('.$id.')')
       }
->all();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$user = User::find();
if(!empty($id))
{
    $user->andWhere('id IN('.$id.')');
}
$command = $user->createCommand();
$data = $command->queryAll();
```

I've try this and it's work for me if you have another solution please let me know.